# No JUnit test found in test with parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parameterized

I'm just learning JUnit testing and I have been given examples of testing with parameters so I'm applying this and the documentation and examples of sites like [Daniel Mayer's Our Craft](https://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/) and [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/).

I'm asked to test the fill() method with a parameterized class. This is the original class:

```
package FuelTankTestPractice;

/**
 * FuelTank is the class which represents the fuel tank of a car.
 * A FuelTank object encapsulates the state information needed for describing the state of the tank:
 * <ul>
 *   <li> tankMax   capacity of the tank
 *   <li> tankLevel fuel level of the tank
 * </ul>
 * 
 * class invariant      0.0 &lt;= tankLevel &lt;= tankMax
 * 
 * @author UC3M MOOC Team
 *
 */
public class FuelTank {

    private double tankMax;
    private double tankLevel;

   /**
    * FuelTank is a constructor of the class. 
    * 
    * <hr>
    * <br> precondition  tankMax &gt; 0.0 and 0.0 &lt;= tankLevel &lt;= getTankMax()  
    * <br> postcondition tankMax &gt; 0.0 and 0.0 &lt;= tankLevel &lt;= getTankMax() 
    * <hr>
    * 
    * @param tankMax  is the amount of fuel  (measured in liters) that the tank can hold
    * @param tankLevel is the amount of fuel (measured in liters) that the tank will have initially
    * 
    */ 
    FuelTank(double tankMax, double tankLevel) {
       this.tankMax   = tankMax;
       this.tankLevel = tankLevel;
    }

   /**
    * getTankLevel is an accessor method
    * 
    * @return   the amount of fuel in the tank
    */
    public double getTankLevel(){
       return tankLevel;
    }

   /**
    * getTankMax is an accessor method
    * 
    * @return   the capacity (in liters) of the tank
    */
    public double getTankMax(){
       return tankMax;
    }

   /**
    * isEmpty gives a status report 
    * 
    * @return   <code>true</code> if the tank is empty 
    *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
    */
    public boolean isEmpty(){
      return tankLevel == 0;
    }

    /**
     * isFull gives a status report 
     * 
     * @return  <code>true</code> if the tank is full 
     *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isFull(){
      return tankLevel == tankMax;
    }

   /**
    * fill is a mutator method that adds fuel to the tank
    * 
    * <hr>
    * <br> precondition     0.0 &lt; amount &lt;= getTankMax() - getTankLevel() 
    * <br> postcondition    not empty
    * <br> postcondition    tankLevel &gt; tankLevel_initial 
    * <hr>
    * 
    * @param amount     the quantity of fuel to add
    * 
    */
    public void fill(double amount){
       tankLevel = tankLevel + amount;
    }

   /**
    * consume is a mutator that consumes amount of fuel
    * 
    * @param amount the amount of fuel to consume
    * 
    */
    public void consume(double amount){
       tankLevel = tankLevel - amount;
    }
}
```

First I had to create a simple test class, that worked without problems:

```
package FuelTankTestPractice;

/**
 * Tests for class FuelTank.
 * 
 * All tests in the folder "test" are executed 
 * when the "Test" action is invoked.
 * 
 */

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;

public class FuelTankTest {

    FuelTank tank = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    tank = new FuelTank(60.0,10.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetTankLevel() {
    tank.getTankLevel();
    assertTrue(tank.getTankLevel()==0.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetTankMax() {
    tank.getTankMax();
    assertTrue(tank.getTankMax()==60.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
    tank.isEmpty();
    assertTrue(!tank.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testHalfFullTank() {
    assertTrue(tank.getTankMax()/2==30.0);
    }

 }
```

But now this is my test class with parameters (the idea is to test the fill() method:

```
package FuelTankTestPractice;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FillingTest extends FuelTankTest{
private double amount;
private double result;

//constructor
public FillingTest (double amount, double result) {
this.amount = amount;
this.result = result;
}

FuelTank tank = new FuelTank(60, 10);

//Declares parameters here
public static Collection<Object[]> fillAmounts(){ 
    Object[][] amounts = new Object[][]{
        {10.0,20.0},
        {15.0,35.0},
        {20.0,30.0},
        {35.0,45.0}}; 
return Arrays.asList(amounts); 
}

@Test   
public void TestFill() {
tank.fill(amount);
assertTrue(amount + tank.getTankLevel() == result);
    }
}
```

The main class and method is pretty simple but I'll add it if it helps:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create the tank
    FuelTank tank = new FuelTank(40.0,0.0);

    System.out.print("The tank with capacity " + tank.getTankMax() + " liters has been created. ");
    System.out.println(" Its initial fuel level is  " + tank.getTankLevel() + " liters.");
}
}
```

I've made many changes to fit with examples, but most of them dont consider another test class (which I require to create a JUnit Test Suite in the end, as instructed). 
Sometimes it throws:

```
java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class FuelTankTestPractice.FillingTest
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:299)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I Hope all this info helps. It's not about to solve my "homework" but about learning. Pleas ask me anything you need before consider as a noob question, I've done all the research I can but I believe examples dont match my question, or maybe I dont know enought to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final working code that passed the test:

```
package FuelTankTestPractice;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

//Part 1: Runwith
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FillingTest {

    private double amount;
    private double result;

    //Part 2: Constructor
    public FillingTest (double amount, double result) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.result = result;
    }

    //Part 3: Declares parameters here
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> fillAmounts(){ 
        Object[][] amounts = new Object[][]{
            {10.0,20.0},
            {15.0,25.0},
            {20.0,30.0},
            {35.0,45.0}}; 
        return Arrays.asList(amounts);
    }

    // Part 4: Test method
    FuelTank tank = new FuelTank(60.0,10.0);    

    @Test
    public void TestFill() {
        tank.fill(amount);
        assertEquals(result, tank.getTankLevel(), 0.0001); 
        // Or assertTrue(tank.getTankLevel() == result);
    }
}
```

Compared to the question code, Part 3 lacks the `@Parameters`line.
Also, the assertTrue() line in Part 4 was wrong, since `tank.fill(amount);`  already added "amount" to TankLevel.

For purposes of the course,I used assertEquals instead of assertTrue (which had me looking for the meaning of "delta").

Comment: This has helped me a lot to learn about JUnit and testing with parameters (I started 2 am. At 5:30 am I decided that I needed StackOverflow help. Thanks to Jägermeister for the answer. Didnt work for me but helped me to recheck all parts of the testing code

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring that your test class should be used as `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`

That implies that it provides a method that carries the`@Parameters` annotation.

Thus: add this annotation to your method `fillAmounts()` and you should be good.

The error message is basically telling you that the runner can't find the method it needs in order to do its job.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer since it actually addresses the issue presented in the question and, is indeed, correct.